# Error occurred while integrating a machine learning model with a flask website

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, flask

I was following a [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deploy-machine-learning-model-using-flask/)  on how to integrate a flask web app to a ML model (I used a Linear Regression model but the model in the tutorial was Decision Tree) but I am getting a
`numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'matmul' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')"` 
[Image showing error in the commandline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pk6F.png)

The code(app.py):

```
def ValuePredictor(to_predict_list):
    to_predict = np.array(to_predict_list).reshape((-1, 5)) 
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open('studentgrades.pkl','rb'))
    result = loaded_model.predict(to_predict)
    return result[0]


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/results", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def results():
    if request.method == "POST":
        # predictions
        to_predict_list=np.array([session['grade1'], session['grade2'], session['absences'],session['failed'], session['hours']])
        predicted = ValuePredictor(to_predict_list)
        session['predicted']=predicted

        return render_template("results.html", name=session['name'],grade1=session['grade1'],grade2=session['grade2'],hours=session['hours'],absences=session['absences'],failed=session['failed'],predicted=session['predicted'])
    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

code(machine learning):

```
data = pd.read_csv("student-mat.csv", sep=";")

predict = "G3"

data = data[["G1", "G2", "absences","failures", "studytime","G3"]]
data = shuffle(data) # Optional - shuffle the data

x = np.array(data.drop([predict], 1))
y =np.array(data[predict])
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1)


# TRAIN MODEL MULTIPLE TIMES FOR BEST SCORE
"""best = 0
for _ in range(20):
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1)

    linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()

    linear.fit(x_train, y_train)
    acc = linear.score(x_test, y_test)
    print("Accuracy: " + str(acc))

    if acc > best:
        best = acc
        with open("studentgrades.pkl", "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(linear, f)"""
# LOAD MODEL
pickle_in = open("studentgrades.pickle", "rb")
linear = pickle.load(pickle_in)
```

Someone please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Add complete error traceback.

Comment: I have added an image showing complete error log on the command line

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like data type mismatch between the training set and the prediction set. You may need to explicitly set data types on the input. Needs to be done by column. e.g.

```
df['G1'].astype('int')
```

Use df.dtypes to check the expected column types.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that your columns are strings and not numbers:

```
In [1]: a = np.zeros(9, np.dtype('<U32')).reshape((3,3))                                                                                 

In [2]: b = np.zeros(9, np.dtype('<U32')).reshape((3,3))                                                                                 

In [3]: a                                                                                                                                
Out[3]: 
array([['', '', ''],
       ['', '', ''],
       ['', '', '']], dtype='<U32')

In [4]: np.matmul(a,b)                                                                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-f6001c33e8b2> in <module>
----> 1 np.matmul(a,b)

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'matmul' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')
```

Comment: Hey. Sorry, I missed this question the other day. I suppose you must have solved it already, but if you haven't, what you have to do is check the dtypes of all the inputs, including the parameters you read from the pickle file. At least some of those will turn out to be strings. If the are strings, you have to change the dtype using the `astype` method. Something like `x = np.array(data.drop([predict], 1)).astype('int')` and so on. You could expand your question showing the inputs you have and we can see.